# Are there hilly areas of Leuven, Belgium?

Tags: where-on-earth, belgium

I am looking for hilly areas in Leuven (with small hills). Google shows Gasthuisberg, but I hope and believe there are more, as I see hilly terrains from Google maps. Can somebody who has been in this region provide more?

Comment: What exactly do you hope to find? There are no significant mountains in Belgium. The highest point in the country is less than 700m above sea level, and most of the hills are no more than 200m. Belgium is one of the [Low Countries](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Countries), so-called precisely because there aren't any hills.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Anyone who has cycled in the Ardennes will disagree with your claim that there are no hills.  Vlaanderen, however, is rather flat.  700 metre is easily high enough to be called a hill.  So is 100 metre.  (Full disclosure: I'm from Holland, and even 10 metre is a hill, in particular if steep enough to sledge down from).

Comment: Some of the confusion here appears to result from the ambiguity between "hill" and "mountain."  There are things that would be called hills in the area, but not mountains.  Can you edit the question to clarify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are small hills near the built-up area of Leuven, including inside the municipal area, and the built-up area is not entirely flat either.  You can find slopes steep enough for a sledge (in case it ever becomes winter again) or to need brakes going down or gears going up by bike.  By standards of the Dutch speaking part of the Low Countries¹, it doesn't get much hillier than this outside the Ardennes or the coastal dunes.  The Leuven town centre is at an elevation of less than 30 metre, and there are hills less than 10 km away which reach over 100 metre elevation, with several more between 80 and 100 metre.

Some examples of hills located in or near Leuven:

Kesselberg area, 4 km from central Leuven.  View from Kesselberg:

[image: Near Kesselberg]
Source: [bvlg blog](https://www.flickr.com/photos/bvlgblog/4096623640/), all rights reserved.

Stairs going up/down Kesselberg:

[image: Kesselberg stairs]
*Source: [mon plaisir, Wikiloc](https://nl.wikiloc.com/routes-wandelen/kessel-lo-abdij-van-vlierbeek-kesselberg-17604515/photo-11105193)*

- The [Tomberg](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomberg_(heuvel)) is a 103 metre high hill in the Meerdaalwoud just south of Leuven, 9 km from the town centre and quite close to the edge of town.  Leuven itself is below 50 metre elevation, so this is clearly a significant¹ hill.
- [Zwanenberg](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/4787823100), 82 metre, 6 km west from train station
- [Steenhoven](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/190758051), around 80 metre, 6 km east from train station
- [Lastberg](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/286027911), around 100 metre, around 8 km east from train station

You can find more by [browsing Opentopomap](https://opentopomap.org/#map=13/50.88105/4.72404), or by [searching overpass-turbo for `natural=peak`](http://overpass-turbo.eu/?template=key-value&key=natural&value=peak).  Here are hills as mapped on Openstreetmap marked against an Openstreetmap rendering (interestingly, Kesselberg is missing here):

[image: Openstreetmap screenshot with hills near Leuven marked]

Or seen on Google Streetview, you'd certainly need some brakes cycling down and gears cycling up [this particular road near Leuven](https://goo.gl/maps/7XcMBGQgwYauzXkW9), or even moreso [this 15% street nearby](https://goo.gl/maps/9p9BE5oNn5sXbjoR6) (thanks to phoog for linking).

¹As defined by being able to tell the difference in which direction you're cycling, even in the absence of wind.

Comment: According to Google Maps, that road is in the municipality of Leuven, not "nearby."  The summit of the hill seems to be on the municipal boundary, however.

Comment: @phoog I use Leuven to mean the built-up area, not the municipality, which is larger (perhaps not that much larger in this case, but in some cases municipalities can be huge).

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful in that case to note as much in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are none. The highest point of the province Vlaams-Brabant, of which Leuven is the capital, is a mere 142 meters high. And even that one is not exactly close to Leuven. You simply don't have the elevation to squeeze in any significant slopes or mountains.

Comment: There certainly are hills in Leuven.  Small hills, to be sure, but hills nonetheless.  There's even a [road with a 15% grade](https://goo.gl/maps/9p9BE5oNn5sXbjoR6).